# dynamic height of chart of highchart

Tags: dynamic, charts, highcharts, height

It is necessary to automaticly and dynamicly change (update) the height of highcharts's charts depending on the amount rows (example, for horizontal bars) on it.

The height of one element (example, horizontal bar) is constant (for example, 20px).
The height of charts with X elements set automaticly (~ 20px * X).

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, you could be starting with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s0zb9z8e/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a little pre-setup.

- Set variables for:

  - the top and bottom margins
  - the point and group padding
  - the width of the points
  - the number of data points in your data set

Calculate and set the chart's `height` property accordingly:

```
var barCount = chartData.length,
    pointWidth = 20,
    marginTop = 70,
    marginRight = 10,
    marginBottom = 50,
    marginLeft = 100,
    groupPadding = 0,
    pointPadding = 0.3,
    chartHeight = marginTop 
                + marginBottom 
                + ((pointWidth * barCount) * (1 + groupPadding + pointPadding));
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/kpu5d1qf/

(update the `dataPoints` variable on the page to see it in action)

Comment: good! cool!!!
but how to implement it when I use drilldown in highcharts

for example
5 primary bars - I calculate chart height func(5)
then user click bar#3 and it 'drill down' to 15 secondary bars
and i can calculate height again

Comment: You can add a function in the `drillDown` and `drillUp` events, that either uses a pre-defined count of the data points, or that retrieves and counts the data points at that time, and uses the `Chart.update()` function to update the `height` property. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update